# select rows with except sqllite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a database with a dataframe that contains the columns: Name, Award, Winner(1 means won and 0 means did not win) and some other things that are irrelevant for this question.

I want to make a dataframe with the names of people that were selected for the award actress(al awards with the name actress in them count), but never won, using `sqlite 3` in python.

These are the first five rows of the dataframe:

```
Unnamed: 0  CeremonyNumber  CeremonyYear    CeremonyMonth   CeremonyDay FilmYear    Award   Winner  Name    FilmDetails
0   0   1   1929    5   16  1927    Actor   1   Emil Jannings   The Last Command
1   1   1   1929    5   16  1927    Actor   0   Richard Barthelmess The Noose
2   2   1   1929    5   16  1927    Actress 1   Janet Gaynor    7th Heaven
3   3   1   1929    5   16  1927    Actress 0   Louise Dresser  A Ship Comes In
4   4   1   1929    5   16  1927    Actress 0   Gloria Swanson  Sadie Thompson
```

I tried it with this query, but this resulted not in the correct result.

```
query = '''
select Name
from oscars
where Award like "Actress%"
except select Name
        from oscars
        where Award like "Actress%" and Winner == 1
'''
```

The outcome of this query should be a dataframe like this:

```
    Name
0   Abigail Breslin
1   Adriana Barraza
2   Agnes Moorehead
3   Alfre Woodard
4   Ali MacGraw
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.)

Comment: it looks more an SQL problem, than a python one, but without knowing the data is difficult to help you

Comment: I edited the question with more data.

Comment: Can you also post what are you getting as the output ?

Comment: The last dataframe in the question are the first 5 rows of the outcome. In total the query gives 301 rows, however i should get a dataframe with 448 rows

Answer (score 0):

In order to select all the actresses who were selected for the award and never won, you should use AND rather than EXCEPT. Something like this should work: 
`SELECT Name from Oscars WHERE Award LIKE "Actress%" AND Winner = 0` 
Refer to the sqlite docs at https://www.sqlite.org/index.html for more information.